# reflections.io Version 0.10.2 looking for a class works in IDE but not when running it as jar

Tags: java, reflection, reflections

Old way of using Reflections doesnt find classes when run from commandline (`java -jar myapp.jar`) anymore, despite being documented as [still supported](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.reflections/reflections/latest/index.html):

```
var reflections = new Reflections("com.package", Scanners.TypesAnnotated, Scanners.SubTypes);
Set<Class<?>> restBaseEnablingClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class);
```

Still works in IDE (Intellij and Eclipse) though...

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug and is documented [here](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/373)

In my case workaround offered there kept giving me `java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation` because the `BuiltinClassLoader` and ClassLoader used by `reflections.io` library were loading jars twice - so I had to specify classloader when instantiating the Reflections class:

```
static Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .setClassLoaders(new ClassLoader[]{
                            ClassLoader.getPlatformClassLoader()
                    })
                    .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("com.package")
            )
        );
```